# How should I incorporate numerical and categorical data as part of the inputs to the U-net for semantic segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, data-preprocessing, u-net, semantic-segmentation, multi-task-learning

I am using a U-Net to segment cancer cells in images of patients' arms. I would like to add patient data to it in order to see if it is possible to enhance the segmentation (patient data comes in the form of a table containing features such as gender, age, etc.). So far, my researches have led me nowhere. What can I do in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called multi-task learning. Here's what you do:

1. Create a second Input.
2. Attach it to 1D CNN (2-3 layers), so it aggregates this tabular information.
3. Concatenate this feature with the intermediate feature generated by the U-Net using Concatenate layer.
4. Put a dense layer of 2 after this.
5. Put softmax with units = number of classes.
6. Add CE loss calculated with this one and the ground labels to the loss of U-Net.

This is in regards to TensorFlow. The same can be done in PyTorch easily.